# How to make Internet Explorer understand my ad hoc jQuery forms?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This simple JavaScript snippet seems to be too complicated for Internet Explorer 8 and even 9 to understand:

```
// Why on the (expletive) hell does Internet Explorer exist?
$('<form/>'>.attr('action', '..') // or ../index.php
            .attr('method', 'post')
            .append(hiddenParam('user', $('#name').val())
            .append(hiddenParam('pass', cryptoFunc($('#pswd').val())
            .submit().remove();
```

Is there any equivalent to my code that doesn't involve much rewriting? (I have quite a lot of these ad hoc jQuery-generated forms in my site.)

Comment: IE may not like that the form is never inserted into the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you add `.appendTo(document.body)` just before `.submit`? E.g.:

```
$('<form/>').attr('action', '..') // or ../index.php
            .attr('method', 'post')
            .append(hiddenParam('user', $('#name').val())
            .append(hiddenParam('pass', cryptoFunc($('#pswd').val())
            .appendTo(document.body)
            .submit().remove();
```

And if that doesn't do it, try giving the browser a moment to catch its breath:

```
var form = $('<form/>');
form.attr('action', '..') // or ../index.php
    .attr('method', 'post')
    .append(hiddenParam('user', $('#name').val())
    .append(hiddenParam('pass', cryptoFunc($('#pswd').val())
    .appendTo(document.body);
setTimeout(function() {
    form.submit().remove();
}, 0);
```

Comment: @Eduardo: Glad that helped. In this particular case, it's probably not unreasonable that you have to add the form to the document before the submit works... :-)

Comment: Why? Somehow the fact a `<form>` can be used to send `HTTP POST` requests is related to its being in an HTML document's body?